# Can link to background-image with URL, but not background-image in root directory

Tags: css

This problem has been setting my nerves off.

I have for example this snippet of code which works:

```
body {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/uN8yFlU.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

And this one which does not:

```
body {
    background-image: url("/resources/navbar-bg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

The only difference between these two code blocks is the way I reference the background image. The former uses a URL, and the latter references a file in the root/resources directory.

My root directory is

- Index.html
- resources
- CSS
- etc.

Comment: I think you messed up the latter code snippit, they look the same to me.

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends where those lines resides, because it is relative to the current file:

```
background-image: url("resources/navbar-bg.png");
```

If your CSS is in `http://example.com/styles.css` it will search for `http://example.com/resources/navbar-bg.png`.

If your CSS is in `http://example.com/theme/styles.css` it will search for `http://example.com/theme/resources/navbar-bg.png`.

If you want to refer to a file in the root directory, just put the path with a slash:

```
background-image: url("/resources/navbar-bg.png");
```

Comment: From what I understand, without the slash, the address means look for the file from the root directory. A slash in front of the address means go back a directory, so actually I would be leaving my root directory, and going up one directory. By the way I tried this back slash anyways, and it didn't work.

Comment: Without the slash, it means look from the current directory (ie. your CSS file directory). With the slash it looks in the top level directory, where your index.html and your resources dir are.

Comment: Ok, I get what you are saying. It's not working though.

Comment: But all my `<img src="#" />` tags work, so I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that already. I used some images that were already working on the site. I also uploaded the same web page to a real server, and the I get the same problem.